# Decrease load time on calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization

Below you see the code for my calender for a website, the problem is that this code takes about 8-10 sec to load. If any of you guys can see a way to minimize the load time I would be grateful.

```
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> AllDatesInMonth(int year, int month)
    {
        foreach (var day in Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)))
        {
            yield return new DateTime(year, month, day);
        }
    }

    public void ForeachDayInMonth(int year, int month, SqlConnection connection)
    {
        int day;
        int count;
        double divHeight;

        lbl_Month.Text += "<table class=\"Month\">";
        foreach (DateTime date in AllDatesInMonth(year, month))
        {
            day = int.Parse(date.ToString().Substring(0, 2));
            count = Begivenheder.Get_Begivenhed_By_Date(year, month, day, connection).Count; // Creates a sql select statement

            lbl_Month.Text += "<tr>" +
                "<td style=\"height: 30px; width: 70px;";

            if (date.Date == DateTime.Today)
            {
                lbl_Month.Text += "-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(000,000,000,0.8);" +
                    "-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(000,000,000,0.8);" +
                    "box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(000,000,000,0.8);";
            }

            lbl_Month.Text += "\">";

            if (count != 0)
            {
                divHeight = 100 / count;

                foreach (Begivenheder b in Begivenheder.Get_Begivenhed_By_Date(year, month, day, connection)) // creates a sql select statement
                {
                    lbl_Month.Text += "<div style=\"background-color: " + b.begivenhed.type.TypeFarve + "; height: " + divHeight + "%;\">" +
                        "<a href=\"KalenderEvent.aspx?Event=" + b.begivenhed.ID + "\">";
                    if (b.begivenhed.Navn.Length > 9)
                    {
                        lbl_Month.Text += b.begivenhed.Navn.Remove(9) + "...";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbl_Month.Text += b.begivenhed.Navn;
                    }
                    lbl_Month.Text += "</a>" +
                        "</div>";
                }
            }

            lbl_Month.Text += "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
        }
        lbl_Month.Text += "</table>";
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string year;

        if (Request.QueryString["Year"] == null)
        {
            year = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            year = Request.QueryString["Year"];
        }

        Page.Title += " - Kalender " + year;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"]);
        connection.Open();
        try
        {
            Year(int.Parse(year), connection);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Year(int year, SqlConnection connection)
    {
        string thisYear = year.ToString();
        int lastYear = year - 1;
        int nextYear = year + 1;

        lbl_Year.Text = "<div>" +
            "<a href=\"Kalender.aspx?Year=" + lastYear.ToString() + "\" id=\"LastYear\"></a>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div>" +
            thisYear +
            "</div>" +
            "<div>" +
            "<a href=\"Kalender.aspx?Year=" + nextYear.ToString() + "\" id=\"NextYear\"></a>" +
            "</div>";

        lbl_Month.Text = "<table>" +
            "<tr>" +
            "<td>";
        // Dage
        lbl_Month.Text += "<p>" +
            "</p>" +
            "<br />" +
            "<table>";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
        {
            lbl_Month.Text += "<tr>" +
                "<td style=\"height: 30px;\">" +
                "<p>" +
                i.ToString() +
                "</p>" +
                "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
        }
        lbl_Month.Text += "</table>" +
            "</td>";

        //Januar (repeats 12 times, ones for each month)
        lbl_Month.Text += "<td>" +
            "<p>" +
            "Januar" +
            "</p>";
        ForeachDayInMonth(int.Parse(thisYear), 1, connection);
        lbl_Month.Text += "</td>";

        lbl_Month.Text += "</tr>" +
            "</table>";
    }
```

heres the "Begivenheder.Get_Begivenhed_By_Date" code.

```
    public static List<Begivenheder> Get_Begivenhed_By_Date(int år, int måned, int dag, SqlConnection connection)
    {
        List<Begivenheder> result = new List<Begivenheder>();

        using (var command = new SqlCommand("Select ID, FK_Begivenhed_ID from Begivenhed_Datoer where Dag=" + dag + " and Måned=" + måned + " and År=" + år, connection))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Begivenheder b = new Begivenheder();
                    b.Dato_ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    b.ID = reader.GetInt32(1);
                    b.Dato_Day = dag;
                    b.Dato_Month = måned;
                    b.Dato_Year = år;
                    result.Add(b);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
            }

            foreach (Begivenheder b in result)
            {
                b.begivenhed = Begivenheder.Get_Begivenhed_By_ID(b.ID, connection);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I know it's a bunch of code, but I have no idea how to decrease it.

Comment: I've just edited your title because it said the opposite of your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every page_load leads to cca 30 database queries - Thats a lot of overhead, try and revamp it so you only need to talk to the database once, if at all. Besides that, get a .NET profiler and see where you spend most time.

Answer (score 2):

You could improve performance by fetching all events for the whole interval, instead of performing one query for each date. It seems that you want all events in one month, given your current data model that's an easy change.

If you *do* choose to perform one query per day, reuse the same `SqlCommand` by adding `SqlParameters` to it, instead of rebuilding a brand new one 28-31 times.

Answer (score 1):

Basic string optimisation would make a big difference. Where you have `string +=` use a string builder instead. Then when all computation is done, convert the StringBuilder to a string with the .ToString() method.

See MSDN [StringBuilder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Also replace the `string + string + string` code with the AppendFormat methods

Comment: Relative to the database hits and the goal of reducing a 10 second page load, this is probably negligible.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use:

```
day = date.Day;
```

instead of:

```
day = int.Parse(date.ToString().Substring(0, 2));
```

2) Put this long style into a stylesheet/CSS, and use a short class='name' instead:

```
webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(000,000,000,0.8);" +
                    "-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(000,000,000,0.8);" +
                    "box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(000,000,000,0.8);
```

3) You are calling Begivenhed_By_Date twice for each day:

```
1)     count = Begivenheder.Get_Begivenhed_By_Date(year, month, day, connection).Count;
2)    foreach (Begivenheder b in Begivenheder.Get_Begivenhed_By_Date(year, month, day, connection))
could be:
+)    List<Begivenheder> hedByDate = Begivenheder.Get_Begivenhed_By_Date(year, month, day, connection);
1.x   count = hedByDate.Count;
2.x   foreach (Begivenheder b in hedByDate, connection))
```

4) At least use StringBuilder to concatenate the lbl_Month.Text += strings first, and then assign it last.

5) Looking into using Repeater controls, so you don't have to litter your code with HTML like this.

6) Change it so you only do a SQL query once, instead of many times.